# Linq to sql проблема с ColumnAttribute(Name)

Tags: c#, linq2sql, .net

```
public class DataColumnStructure : IGetData
{
    [Column(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "id_parent")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
public class MasterDataContext : DataContext
{
    public IEnumerable<DataColumnStructure> GetColumns(int objectId)
    {
       return ExecuteQuery<DataColumnStructure>
                (GetColumns_Sql("sysCol.object_id = @p0"), new object[] {objectId});
    }
}
```

Почему `Parent_id` не хочет присваиваться при указанном `[Column(Name = "id_parent")]`?
Если же зделать так `public int Id_Parent { get; set; }`, то всё вытаскивается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал эту фичу и не сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Есть мысль, что это из-за знака подчёркивания.

Я бы порекомендовал в запросе явно указать `SELECT id_parent AS ParentID FROM ...`

Comment: это не из-за подчёркивания, когда ссылаешься на объект типа таблица, представление, процедура, функция, всё вытаскивается как нужно при указанном ColumnAttribute(name), а когда используешь ExecuteQuery то он просто напросто не смотрит на ColumnAttribute и сравнивает сами свойства независимо от ColumnAttribute. Возможно это небольшой бажик, а может так и было задумано :)). Придётся называть свойства как выбранные поля но ColumnAttribute.